# React Native Grid that uses varying item sizes in an overlapping layout?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm wondering if it would be possible to create some sort of grid layout like this in React Native, where I alternate between different item sizes (for this we can keep it easy and just say we have a small medium and large size that are all based on some ratio of eachother) and lay them out in an overlapping grid?

[image: Grid Example]

Answer (score 0):

I've honestly been trying to work this out for my own project myself. The closest I've come is modifying the code for `react-native-masonry-list` with different use cases but I'm chasing every one all the way down so nothing promising.

Essentially you're mapping over all the content and checking if it follows the mathematical pattern of i % numColumns === num. Essentially (item index) modulo (numColimns) === (current row / column). I'm trying to alter this by skipping certain numbers if the column previous had an element that should 'span' across but it's an absolute nightmare.

My best advice at this point is to avoid it at this point if it can be helped.